# PHP $string{0} vs. $string[0];

Tags: php, string

In PHP you can access characters of strings in a few different ways, one of which is substr().  You can also access the Nth character in a string with curly or square braces, like so:

```
$string = 'hello';

echo $string{0}; // h
echo $string[0]; // h
```

My question is, is there a benefit of one over the other? What's the difference between {} and []?

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

use `$string[0]`, the other method (braces) has been removed in PHP 8.0.

For [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Accessing characters within string literals using the {} syntax has been deprecated in PHP 7.4. This has been removed in PHP 8.0.

And for [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Prior to PHP 8.0.0, square brackets and curly braces could be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} would both do the same thing in the example above). The curly brace syntax was deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0 and no longer supported as of PHP 8.0.0.

Comment: Will the use of {} as a method of evaluation be removed also?
E.g
${$dynamic_object_name}->doStuff()

Comment: nope, i believe their goal is to just standardize accessing strings as array.

Comment: For future reference I'd like to note that the line about curly syntax being deprecated has since been removed from the documentation about 3 years ago which means it's not going to be deprecated any time soon, if ever.

Comment: @Owen: PHP also uses `{}` for array access. It always did. (Just saying)

Comment: Downvoted as v.out of date. PHP6 never happened. Pacerier's answer is much more accurate now.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, however it should be updated to reflect the PHP7 reality, i.e. `$string{0}` is deprecated in 7.4 - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access

Answer (score 20):

[**There is no difference.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809707/632951) Owen's answer is outdated, the latest version of PHP Manual no longer states that it is deprecated [§](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. **Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose**. [...]
>
> Note: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, **for
>   the same purpose**.

However it seems that more people/projects use `[]`, and that many people don't even know `{}` is possible. If you need to share your code publicly or with people who don't know the curly brace syntax, it **may** be beneficial to use `[]`.

UPDATED : accessing string characters with `{}` is deprecated, use `[]` instead.

Comment: I prefer curly braces because it makes it visually clear that I'm accessing a char from a string variable, not a value from an array. On some level, that's the same thing, but on the code level, it makes it visually nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's no difference. This language quirk has some history...

Originally, the curly brace syntax was intended to replace the square bracket syntax which was going to be deprecated:

http://web.archive.org/web/20010614144731/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr.

Later that policy was reversed, and the square brackets syntax was preferred instead:

http://web.archive.org/web/20060702080821/http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

and even later, the curly braces one was going to be deprecated:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080612153808/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

As of this writing, it seems that the deprecation has been withdrawn as well and they are just considered two alternative syntaxes:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160607224929/http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Answer (score 2):

Curly brace access was deprecated in PHP 7.4

> Array and string offset access using curly braces ¶
>
> The array and string offset access syntax using curly braces is
> deprecated. Use $var[$idx] instead of $var{$idx}.

[PHP 7.4 Deprecated Features, PHP Core](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php#migration74.deprecated.core.array-string-access-curly-brace)