# Array-like statement with curly brackets - what is the purpose?

Tags: php

I found this snippet of code online and I was wondering what it does:

```
$k[$i] = ord($key{$i}) & 0x1F;
```

I know that `ord()` returns an ASCII value, but I'm unclear on what the curly brackets do `$key{$i}` and also what this does `& 0x1F`.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8092248/632951

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an array syntax. It's for accessing single characters from strings only. The index must be numeric.

```
 $str{1} == $str[1]
```

It's briefly mentioned here in the info box:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

<s>Also, it's officially declared deprecated.</s> It has been on and off supposed deprecation in the manual, but is still very valid, if uncommon, syntax.

---

The `& 0x1F` is a bit-wise AND. In this case it limits the decimal values to 0 till 31.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. In fact, as I explain in my answer, the curly bracket syntax is a fully valid (not deprecated) alternative to square bracket syntax. The reference that mario links to only underscores my point--the two forms are equivalent.

Comment: @Ochado Good catch. That's no longer relevant. Previous versions of the manual *did* [label it as deprecated for PHP 5.3](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13900), and once before pertaining 6.0 as seen [in the DE-version](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php). So better duplicate: [PHP $string{0} vs. $string\[0\];](http://stackoverflow.com/q/335205) (Personally I've also secretly still been using the `{1}` syntax for decorative purposes, btw.)

Comment: The index does **not** need to be only numeric. PHP will do a conversion automatically.

Comment: @Pacerier: I guess I wanted to imply [`is_numeric("1")`](http://php.net/is_numeric). But you're right; it's more of a custom int cast/cut for string indicies.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, either [square brackets] or {curly braces} are fully legal, interchangeable means of accessing an array:

> Note: Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Both are fully valid; curly braces are not deprecated.

Concerning "& 0x1F", others like @Tadek have responded:

> & is a binary operator. See more in the documentation [http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php]. It sets the bits if they are set in both variables.

Comment: Consider of removing comments on other answers from your own answer.

Comment: I've edited this answer to remove your comment about the accepted answer (which might not always *be* the accepted answer). Consider downvoting and/or commenting on other answers if you think they're correct. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, just let your answer speak for itself.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for the edit. As I'm new to contributing to Stack Overflow, I appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

**First part of your question: curly braces**

This is about referencing the value of the variable.

In your example, if `$i` is equal to `123`, then

```
$k[$i] = ord($key{$i}) & 0x1F;
```

will be the same as

```
$k[123] = ord($key[123]) & 0x1F;
```

**Second part of your question: '&' sign**

`&` is a binary operator. See more [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It sets the bits if they are set in both variables.

Answer (score 3):

The `& 0x1F` is a bit-wise operation, used to "normalize" values of characters, colors, etc, that are put into hex but aren't necessarily "read" the same. Read more on [Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

```
& 0x1f
```

is equivalent to

```
& 00011111
```

This can effective set the first three bits of any byte-sized value to 0.

```
0xff & 0x1f
```

results in

```
0x1f
```

or

```
11111111 & 00011111
```

results in

```
00011111
```