# string - array ambiguity in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I dimly recall, from my first readings of the PHP docs (more than 10 years ago) that the array-like syntax to access characters in arrays (`$string[0]`) posed some ambiguity or undefined behaviour.

The O'Reilly PHP Pocket Reference (2nd ed) states:

> To solve an ambiguity problem between strings and arrays, a
>   new syntax has been introduced to dereference individual characters
>   from strings:
>
> `$string{2}`
>
> This syntax is equivalent to `$string[2]`, and is preferable.

I understand that `$string[2]` might be confusing, but I'm not sure how it could be ambiguous?

Furthermore: I wonder how [the new syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) `$string{2}` removes the ambiguity/confusion, considering that the curly braces  ([apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092248/php-curly-braces-in-array-notation)) also work for "real" arrays.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand it correctly but i don't see a problem here, since $string{2} (or $string[2]) is used to either, from the perspective of this being a string, select the 2nd character or from the perspective of an array, retreive the 2nd element, which is basically the same thing for the interpreter since a string is just an array too for the interpreter.

Comment: latest php version gets weird `$str = 'hi'; echo $str[0][0][0][0][0][0][0];//outputs h`, just recursively does substr for the first char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only ambiguity is that if you're expecting an array, but actually have a string, `$var[0]` will give you the first byte of the string instead of the first array element. This may lead to a lot of head scratching and wondering why PHP is only giving you the first character instead of the whole array element. This is even more true for non-numeric indexes like `$var['foo']`, which actually works if `$var` is a string (yeah, please don't ask). I.e. it may make debugging slightly more difficult if your program is wrong in the first place.

There's no ambiguity for correct programs, since a variable cannot be a string and an array at the same time.

Comment: +1 and a rant: This is a typical PHP "solution" that... solves nothing. With `[]` by mistake on a string you get an unexpected result while with `{}` by mistake on an array you also get an unexpected result since you were always expecting one character only. Of course that's not true because as the OP says `{}` works "normally" on arrays too, so now `{}` has the same problem that `[]` had that led to `{}` being introduced. Perhaps a future attempt will manage to get this right before we run out of punctuaction. Ugh.

Comment: `$var['foo']` works because PHP knows it's not an array, 'foo' is not a valid key for this non-array, so its coerced into a 0 and becomes `$var[0]`

Comment: @Marc Yes, there's an explanation, but that doesn't really make it better. :) The behavior in 5.4 of at least triggering a notice makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Many problems caused by the ambiguity between string offsets and array offsets have been removed with the changes in 5.4, which is after the publish date of your reference.   http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

For this reason, I'd reccomend [] for string offsets in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have tested some variables with this code:

```
<pre><?php 

dumpling(array("php"));
dumpling(array());
dumpling(0);
dumpling(1);
dumpling(TRUE);
dumpling(FALSE);
dumpling(NULL);
dumpling("php");

function dumpling($var){
    var_dump($var[0]);
    var_dump($var{0});
}

?>
```

and there didn't seem to be any difference between those two.

The output was :

```
string(3) "php"
string(3) "php"
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
string(1) "p"
string(1) "p"
```

Comment: The output of `array(TRUE)` was `bool(TRUE);bool(TRUE);` BTW if someone wonders :)