# how can i use for loop scope variable form outside for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I face a problem about the following code.

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE sub_id=$subject_id";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$question_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
for($a=1;$a<=$question_count;$a++){
    $ans{$a}=$_POST["ans$a"];
    $subject_id{$a}=$_POST["sub_id$a"];
    $group_id{$a}=$_POST["grup_id$a"];  
}

?>
```

I want to use `$ans{$a}`, `$subject_id{$a}`, `$subject_id{$a}` etc variable outside for loop. If I use those like following code,

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE sub_id=$subject_id";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$question_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
for($a=1;$a<=$question_count;$a++){
    $ans{$a}=$_POST["ans$a"];
    $subject_id{$a}=$_POST["sub_id$a"];
    $group_id{$a}=$_POST["grup_id$a"];
}

    echo $ans1;
    echo $subject_id1;
?>
```

php says that:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: ans1 in F:\xampp\htdocs\oes\Student\result_process.php on line 25.

please help me give some advice to use these variable outside for loop scope.

Comment: I haven't used such constructs as I think it is bad practice to use them. But shouldn't it be `${"ans".$a}` instead of `$ans{$a}`

Comment: In your loop, do you mean to write: `${'ans' . $a}`? In other words dynamically creating a variable, such as `$ans1`?

Comment: yes i want it. that's variable dynamically create $ans1. i will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `$ans{$a}` is equal to `$ans[$a]` ([PHP curly braces in array notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092248/php-curly-braces-in-array-notation))

So your loop does this:

```
 for($a=1;$a<=$question_count;$a++){
     $ans[$a]=$_POST["ans$a"];
     $subject_id[$a]=$_POST["sub_id$a"];
     $group_id[$a]=$_POST["grup_id$a"];  
 }
```

That's why `$ans1` is not defined. If you would write `echo $ans[1]` you would get the result.

If you really want a variable called `$ans1` you would need to write it that way:

```
 for( $a = 1 ; $a <= $question_count ; $a++ ){
     ${"ans" . $a} = $_POST["ans$a"];
     ${"subject_id" . $a} = $_POST["sub_id$a"];
     ${"group_id" . $a} = $_POST["grup_id$a"];  
 }
```

But as I wrote in my comment I think this way of writing code should be avoided.

Comment: Sorry this code also show same problem. still now it say.
Notice: Undefined variable: ans3 in F:\xampp\htdocs\oes\Student\result_process.php on line 65
 i want to use ans3 variable.

it work if i use such like this variable ${"ans" . $a} instead of $ans[$a]

Comment: @Sifat080 If you can access `$ans1` but `$ans3` would result in an `Notice: Undefined variable: ans3`  then `$question_count` is smaller then `3`.  What do you want to say with `it work if i use such like this variable ${"ans" . $a} instead of $ans[$a]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible variable $question_count can be 0.
Otherwise try to use arrays:

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE sub_id=$subject_id";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$question_count=mysql_num_rows($query);
$items = array();

for($a=1;$a<=$question_count;$a++){
    $items[$a] = array(
       'ans' => $_POST["ans$a"],
       'subject_id' => $_POST["sub_id$a"],
       'group_id' => $_POST["grup_id$a"]
    );
}

echo $items[1]['ans'];
echo $items[1]['subject_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Even if `$question_count`  would never be `0`, `$ans1` would never be set with the code given by the OP  as `$ans{$a}` is equal to `$ans[$a]`.