# PHP arrays -- square brackets vs curly braces ($array[$i] vs $array{$i})

Tags: php

As i recently learned `$myArray[$index]` in PHP is equivalent to `$myArray{$index}`.

This mentioned on [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also i found small discussion here: [PHP curly braces in array notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092248/php-curly-braces-in-array-notation).

[PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) does not contains any recommendations about which way is preferable.

So, my question is -- it's just a matter of taste or may be some objective reasons to use one or the other syntax?

Comment: Just use the first way like everybody else does.

Comment: @PeeHaa actually i always use this syntax, but i faced with piece of code where used second syntax (mixed with first). and i was confused a little

Comment: Is there any reason why you would use a syntax, I've personally never seen before anywhere?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it is not my code, i just faced with this and was wondered if here is any real difference

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*"Square bracket notation"* for array elements would be more unified and acceptable.
"Curly bracket notation" will work in expressions but not in variable interpolation when dealing with accessing of an array element.
Consider the following example:

```
$myArray = [1,2];
$index = 1;

echo "value at index $index is $myArray[$index]"; // outputs "value at index 1 is 2"

echo "value at index $index is $myArray{$index}"; // will throw "Notice: Array to string conversion"

var_dump($myArray{$index});   // outputs "int(2)"
```