# Accessing characters in a string using array syntax

Tags: php, string

Suppose we have this code`$test = 'text';`. What's the difference between `echo $test[0]` and `echo $test{0}`? The result is the same.

Is it a good practice to treat a variable which contains a string like a array of character?

Comment: *"What's the diferece betwen echo $test[0] and echo $test{0}? The result is the same."* In conclusion, by the definition of difference, there is no difference.

Comment: If there is no diference. Why i should use $foo[n] or $foo{n}? What's the better one?

Comment: To quote the manual: "Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 6. Use square brackets instead."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335205/php-string0-vs-string0?rq=1

Comment: @fab Why don't you post your comment as an answer? It is the right and full answer to the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, I'll aggregate my comments as an answer:

To quote the manual

> Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the
>   same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 7 .
>   Use square brackets instead.

Also, albeit undocumented, the {} accessor also works for arrays, which makes $foo{$bar} and $foo[$bar] completely equivalent. It's just old syntax for the convenience of Perl programmers.

Concerning your second question, if it is good practice to treat strings like an array of characters: Yes, if it is useful for your task, do it. In low level languages like C, strings *are* arrays of characters, so it is quite natural to treat them like that.

BUT keep in mind that PHP has bad unicode support. So if your string is in multi-byte encoding (ie UTF-8), this might not work as expected. Better use the [multibyte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) in that case.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> Accessing characters within string literals using the {} syntax has been deprecated in PHP 7.4. This has been removed in PHP 8.0.

So, **always** use square brackets `$str[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write "Hello, I am a character of a string $string{0}"

But you can not write "Hello, I am a character of a string $string[0]"

You have to use string concatenation sign like
"Hello, I am a character of a string " . $string[0];

Comment: Adding to this,  "Hello, I am a character of a string {$string[0]}" ("complex string syntax" is what it's called) is fine too.

Comment: You don't need to use string concatenation. You can just use braces, like @Hissvard said.